# How to know the format of an USB camera?

Tags: linux, windows, usb, video-capture

i.e. the format that the camera uses to transfer the captured video to PC, like YUV444/YUV422/YUV420/RGB/MJPEG, etc.

Windows or Linux. I'm on Windows 10, but can connect it to linux VM to detect the format if methods on Linux is available.

Comment: I use a utility called [MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo) (Open Source) to inspect video files to see what type they are (and look at other metadata). Or are you talking about a webcam / streaming camera?

Comment: @ Smock I'm talking about webcam / streaming camera. For files, you can use ffprobe from ffmpeg too.